# Recursive function that sums the odd digits of an integer

Tags: c, recursion

For instance n = 8135267 => 16
Here is a solution but I don't understand it.

```
int sumOddDigits(int n) {

if(n == 0)
   return 0;

if(n%2 == 1) //if n is odd
   //returns last digit of n + sumOddDigits(n/10) => n/10 removes the last digit of n
   return n % 10 + sumOddDigits(n/10) 

else
   return sumOddDigits(n/10); 

}
```

Comment: The code is clear and simple. So what's your question?

Comment: Pick a smaller number and walk through this on paper.  Really, that will be just as clear as any explanation you can get here.

Comment: Have you tried running it step-wise in a debugger and looking at what happens?

Comment: @Georg Fritzsche: Recursive algorithms are notoriously difficult to step through. I wouldn't recommend it to a beginner.

Comment: This code breaks for negative inputs.

Comment: @R.. It may or may not. The signedness of a modulus result against a signed number isn't defined by the standard.

Comment: @Justin: Apparently you forgot to read ISO/IEC 9899:1999...

Comment: @TonyK: Sorry, but i don't see what's harder about debugging a recursive function than normal code calling other functions etc. The principle remains the same.

Comment: @R.. Not all compilers are C99-compliant.

Comment: "The standard" is C99. And I've never seen an implementation where division of negative numbers deviates from the (ugly) C99-specified behavior, even though old versions of the standard allowed either this ugly behavior or the sane, correct behavior.

Comment: @Georg Fritzsche: I see that you've never written a chess program.

Comment: @TonyK: I don't see why that should be more difficult because of *recursion* alone. It would be the algorithm, complexity, ... Anyway, if the above is too complex for someone to understand from stepping through in debugger or on paper they might as well want to choose a different occupation.

Comment: @Georg: I had never thought to use a debugger to step through code,but after using it, it was pretty clear what was going on.

Comment: Great. Reading my last comment again: i didn't mean to diss you or anyone learning with the occupation part :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integer divison by ten "cuts off" the last digit: I.e. `1234/10` results in `123`.

Modulo 10  returns the last digit: i.e. `1234%10` results in `4`.

Thus, the above code considers always the last digit. If the last digit is odd (hence the `%2==1` stuff) it will be counted, otherwise not. So, if it should count the digit, it takes the last digit (the `% 10`-stuff) and continues computing with the remaining digits (the recursion with the `/10`-stuff) and adding them to the digit. If the current digit shall not be counted, it continues just with the remaining digits (thus the recursion and the `/10`-stuff) without adding it to the current digit.

If the argument is 0, this means that the whole number is traversed, thus the function terminates with returning 0.

Answer (score 1):

% is the [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator. It basically finds the remainder of dividing by a number.

n %2 n is only 1 if it's odd. % 10 gets the remainder of the dividing the number by 10, this gets you the currently last digit. Integer division by 10 gets you the next digit as the current last digit (1567/10 = 156)

Answer (score 0):

Think about it this way:  Starting with your known answer of `8135267 => 16`, if I asked you for the sum of the odd digits in ***3***8135267, what would *you* do?  What if I asked for ***4***8135267?  How do your manual steps related to that function?

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way. If you get an even digit your function returns it + function value of the number without that digit. Otherwise it returns the function value of the number without the last digit. On your example:

```
813526(7) -> 0 + sumEvenDigits(813526)
                       6 + sumEvenDigits(81352)
                                 2 + sumEvenDigits(8135)
                                          ....
                                            8 + sumEvenDigits(0)
                                                      0 = 16
```

Comment: You've shown it adding the even digits rather than the odd digits (which just happens to have the same sum in this case).

Answer (score 0):

```
int sum_odd_digits(int n)
{
  int s=0,r=0;
  if(n==0)
    return 0;
  r = n%10;
  if(r%2==1)
  s = s+r;
  n=n/10;
  
  return s+ sum_odd_digits(n);
}
```